# Handle NULL value for Dynamic SQL (insert)

Tags: sql-insert

I have created stored procedure with few input parameters  which then passed to  dynamic SQL commands.  When I pass 'NULL' to one of the input parameters the whole dynamic SQL statement becomes NULL.  Sample code is:

```
DECLARE @FName VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @MName VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @LName VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @InsertSql VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @FName = 'John';
SET @MName = NULL;
SET @LName = 'Williams';

SET @InsertSql = 'INSERT INTO  TestName (TestIDFirstName,TestMiddleName,TestLastName) Values (''' + @FName + ''',''' + @MName + ''',''' + @LName + ''')';

SELECT @InsertSql; --Returns NULL.
```

How do I handle when any of the input parameters has NULL value.  I want to handle this case with one Insert statement.

Comment: 1. Which database? 2. If your real code is remotely similar to this, you are pretty much asking for SQL injection. Please read about it before continuing.

Comment: While joining/concating string in SQL, if any one is NULL, it will return NULL. so use ISNULL or COALESCE on doubtful variable.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, is MSSQL database

Answer (score 2):

USE <kbd>[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190349.aspx)</kbd>

```
SET @InsertSql = 'INSERT INTO  TestName (TestIDFirstName,TestMiddleName,TestLastName) Values (''' +COALESCE(@FName,'') + ''',''' + COALESCE(@MName,'') + ''',''' + COALESCE(@LName,'') + ''')';
```

Comment: it works but I do not want to insert empty string for the nullable column.  I want to insert NULL as such.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to replace the insertSQL statement to:

```
SET @InsertSql = 
'INSERT INTO TestName (TestIDFirstName,TestMiddleName,TestLastName) 
 Values
 (''' + @FName + ''','
 + CASE WHEN cast ( @MName as varchar) IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE cast(''''+@MName+'''' as varchar) END
 + ',''' + @LName + ''')';
```

if `@MName` is null @InsertSql equals to:

```
INSERT INTO TestName (TestIDFirstName,TestMiddleName,TestLastName)     Values    ('John',NULL,'Williams')
```

else

```
INSERT INTO TestName (TestIDFirstName,TestMiddleName,TestLastName)     Values    ('John','Florian','Williams')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CONCAT works:

```
DECLARE @FName VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @MName VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @LName VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @InsertSql VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @FName = 'John';
SET @MName = NULL;
SET @LName = 'Williams';

SET @InsertSql = CONCAT ('INSERT INTO  TestName (TestIDFirstName,TestMiddleName,TestLastName) Values (''', @FName, ''',','''', @MName, ''',''',@LName, ''')')           

SELECT @InsertSql; --Returns NULL.
```

Comment: when I execute with concat, am getting error "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 50
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: I believe the "concat" function was added in SQL server 2012 so you would need to be on this version or later.